# How many vertices of degree n-k-1, for a self-complementary graph with m vertices of degree k

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I literally have no idea how to approach this problem. I thought about splitting it into cases, where m or k is either even or odd. If anybody could help me out, this would be very much appreciated.

Suppose that a self-complementary graph G has exactly m vertices of degree
k (for some k). How many vertices of degree n − k − 1 must G have?

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ has $m$ vertices of degree $k$ then the complement of $G$ has $m$ vertices of degree $n-k-1$.

Since $G$ is its own complement it has $m$ vertices of degree $n-k-1$.

Comment: I don't really see how "If G has m vertices of degree k" implies that the complement of G has m vertices of degree n - k -1. Could you please go a bit more into detail?

Comment: If a vertex has degree $k$ in a graph $G$ then that means it is joined to $k$ vertices in $G$. However there are $n-1$  vertices which it could be joined to and so it is joined to the other $n-1-k$ vertices in the complement. (By the definition of complement.)